# Why AbstractOwnableSynchronizer.exclusiveOwnerThread is not declared as volatile?

Tags: java, volatile, reentrantlock

While reading the source code of `java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock` I found that the `tryLock()` method is implemented as below:

```java
        final boolean nonfairTryAcquire(int acquires) {
            final Thread current = Thread.currentThread();
            int c = getState();
            if (c == 0) {
                if (compareAndSetState(0, acquires)) {
                    setExclusiveOwnerThread(current);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else if (current == getExclusiveOwnerThread()) {
                int nextc = c + acquires;
                if (nextc < 0) // overflow
                    throw new Error("Maximum lock count exceeded");
                setState(nextc);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

We try to "own" the lock or check if we have already owned the lock, depending on the `state` maintained in `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer`. But I wonder why the variable `state` is declared as **volatile** but the  variable `exclusiveOwnerThread` is not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand why `exclusiveOwnerThread` does not need to be volatile it helps to look at both the acquire and release methods together.

Acquire method<sup>1</sup>:

```java
/**
 * Performs non-fair tryLock.  tryAcquire is implemented in
 * subclasses, but both need nonfair try for trylock method.
 */
@ReservedStackAccess
final boolean nonfairTryAcquire(int acquires) {
    final Thread current = Thread.currentThread();
    int c = getState();
    if (c == 0) {
        if (compareAndSetState(0, acquires)) {
            setExclusiveOwnerThread(current);
            return true;
        }
    }
    else if (current == getExclusiveOwnerThread()) {
        int nextc = c + acquires;
        if (nextc < 0) // overflow
            throw new Error("Maximum lock count exceeded");
        setState(nextc);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Release method:

```java
@ReservedStackAccess
protected final boolean tryRelease(int releases) {
    int c = getState() - releases;
    if (Thread.currentThread() != getExclusiveOwnerThread())
        throw new IllegalMonitorStateException();
    boolean free = false;
    if (c == 0) {
        free = true;
        setExclusiveOwnerThread(null);
    }
    setState(c);
    return free;
}
```

It's also important to realize that `exclusiveOwnerThread` does not reference some arbitrary object with no relation to the threads involved. It specifically holds a reference to a `Thread` instance and is compared strictly to the calling thread. In other words, what matters is if:

```java
Thread.currentThread() == getExclusiveOwnerThread()
```

Which will be true if, and only if, the calling thread has previously invoked `#setExclusiveOwnerThread(Thread)`, with itself as the argument, due to the combined natures of `#nonfairTryAcquire(int)` and `#tryRelease(int)`. Actions in one thread always *happen-before* subsequent actions in the same thread.

So if `c != 0` then there are two scenarios:

1. The calling thread owns the synchronizer.

   - Since actions in one thread always *happen-before* subsequent actions in the same thread it is guaranteed `getExclusiveOwnerThread()` will return a reference to the calling thread.
2. The calling thread *does not* own the synchronizer.

   - It no longer matters what reference is returned by `getExclusiveOwnerThread()` because it is *impossible* for that method to return a reference to the calling thread.

     The calling thread can never see a stale reference to itself because of the `setExclusiveOwnerThread(null)` call in `#tryRelease(int)`. This means `getExclusiveOwnerThread()` can either return `null` or some other `Thread` reference (stale or not), but never a reference to the calling thread.

The reason `state` must be volatile is because it is shared between threads in a manner where it's paramount each thread sees the most recent value.

---

<sup>1. The implementation of `FairSync#tryAcquire(int)` has nearly the same implementation except it takes the order of calling threads into account.</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer :) I agree that it works well when a thread compares itself to the `exclusiveOwnerThread` value, because of the _happens-before_ rule within a single thread. If the thread has owned the lock, it will definitely get the right `exclusiveOwnerThread` (which refers to itself) when reentering or unlocking. And it's sufficient to guarantee that the thread doesn't see a stale value that refers to itself if the thread doesn't own the lock (done by `setExclusiveOwnerThread(null)`), as you said.

Comment: But what also confuse me is that there is a `getOwner()` method defined in `ReentrantLock`, which returns the `exclusiveOwnerThread` in case `c !=0`. While in the `c == 0` branch of `nonfairTryAcquire()`, the `exclusiveOwnerThread` variable is set **after** a volatile-write (which acts like unlocking, for memory consistency) to the state. So I think the `getOwner()` method may return a stale value of `exclusiveOwnerThread` even though it always trigger a volatile-read (which acts like locking, for memory consistency) on the state before the read of `exclusiveOwnerThread`...

Comment: The documentation of [`ReentrantLock#getOwner()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#getOwner()) says, "_When this method is called by a thread that is not the owner, the return value reflects a best-effort approximation of current lock status_". I interpret that to mean it there's explicitly no guarantee you'll see the correct value if the calling thread does not own the lock.

Comment: sorry that I forgot to read the documentation of that method... Thanks a lot.